# jquery masonry broken when changing line height

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have a few options for people with poor eyesight one of which is to change the `line-height` from a menu, however, when the `line-height` is changed, masonry blocks overlap each other. When I re-size the window to very small and then back up again, everything looks fine. Reloading the page doesn't help.
Where should I add what event to make it work?
The `line-height` applies to all the elements, not only masonry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try reloading masonry after a new line-height is selected.

```
$(#your_masonry_container').masonry( 'reload' );
```

It is used in this demo - http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html